# Java scanner will not read args

Tags: java, input

My teacher gave us pre written code for a scanner but it's not working.  I even commented out my code and ran the prewritten code independently to see if it was my fault and it's not.
How do I correct my teacher's error?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Project2
{
public static void main (String args[]) throws Exception
{
    // Create a scanner to read from keyboard
    Scanner infile = new Scanner ( new FileReader(args[0]) );
    int count=0,sum=0, largest=Integer.MIN_VALUE,smallest=Integer.MAX_VALUE, evens=0, odds=0;
    double average=0.0;
```

the code i'm showing is just the beginning part.
how do I fix this?

My error message.

```
Matthews-MacBook-Pro-4:Java MatthewSimon$ javac Project2.java
Matthews-MacBook-Pro-4:Java MatthewSimon$ java Project2 ints.txt















sf
sdf
e
23
6
57
5 
z
sfd
34
5
^[[A^[[Afs
d
^CMatthews-MacBook-Pro-4:Java MatthewSimon$
```

i have to control+c to exit the program. after the program runs its just a blank line...
i'm using a mac/terminal by the way.

Comment: and how are you calling this code?

Comment: I did not write this!
So if that is the problem how do I fix it?

Comment: What is this code supposed to do? What does it actually do?

Comment: The above code is supposed to read a file using the scanner.
The assignment is to take the file that is read by scanner and manipulate it but I can't even get to that part without seeing why the first part isn't running on it's own.

Comment: args is command line input, so again I ask how are you calling this code?

Comment: Are you passing a path to a file to the program as the first argument?

Comment: Show us that command and the error you receive

Comment: @ScaryWombat java Project2 ints.txt

Comment: And where is `ints.txt` file located?

Comment: and what is the error?

Comment: Can you spell out what do you consider your teacher's error and why?

Comment: @WeekzSO ,argument in main must be pass on a console when you call your java class or in Eclipse you will set the argument in main in run configuration settings.

Comment: @PM77-1 ints.txt is located in the same folder as the java file

Comment: That error message doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @BitNinja the error is that instead of running code..it just has blank space that i can type into.

Comment: This NOT an error message.

Comment: @PM77-1 this the result. its not an error message but rather the incorrect response from the code.

Comment: Can you add in the code where values are *supposed* to be read from the text file?

Comment: @MikeK that code isn't written yet.  They will be written inside a while loop because those are my instructions but there is no point since I cannot even run the prewritten code my teacher gave me.

Comment: Well in that case, I don't see any real effort made by yourself before coming to ask for help

Comment: @MikeK effort was made and I was aided by those who saw it. Good day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are simply compiling the code or running through an IDE, it won't process the command line argument by default.

Try:

```
javac Project2.java
java Project2 test.txt
```

That will pass in a file called test.txt as the arg[0].  This assumes there is a file called test.txt in the same directory as Project2.java.

This should get you started.  I think you will want to simply loop through the Scanner and perform the calculations.  I have done 2 as an example.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Project2
{
    public static void main (String args[]) throws Exception
    {
        // Create a scanner to read from keyboard
        Scanner infile = new Scanner ( new FileReader(args[0]) );
        int count=0,sum=0, largest=Integer.MIN_VALUE,smallest=Integer.MAX_VALUE, evens=0, odds=0;
        double average=0.0;

        while (infile.hasNext() == true ) {
            count += 1;
            sum += infile.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.println("Count: " + count + "\tSum: " + sum);
    }
}
```

Comment: He is already doing this.

Comment: that's what i did...all that stuff before it is just my terminal showing the folder it's in

Comment: That looks exactly like the OP's current terminal commands

Comment: @Trinculo at least he accepted your answer to appreciate your effort